# FullCalendar issue while pulling data for second time on button click

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar

I'm giving a date as an input and with the help of ajax call getting the data oriented for that particular date, while doing so I'm getting the data successfully for the first time. If i do the same the second time, I'm getting the first time data again for any date selected.

I thought the Issue to happens in this line,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', NewDate);
```

Where i'm trying to move the calendar to the date selected, After this line im seeing the date selected getting changed to the date which is selected first time. If i refresh the page and try again it works as it believe as first request. But without this line the request for the second time is not getting completed totally.

Example: If i select the date as March-16 2015 and click on View button, I will see the list of events with start and end date in calendar for March 16, and if i try the same second time as July 13 2015, I will see the results of March 16 coming up again rather than July13.

I'm sharing my code below,

```
$scope.view = function(){
        document.getElementById("calendar").style.display="block";
        var portfolio = $scope.selectedPortfolioList.portfolio; 
        var period = $scope.selectedPeriod.period;
        var week = $scope.selectedWeek.week;
        var sDate = $("#bDate").val();
var json = { "portfolio" : portfolio, "week" : week, "period": period, "sDate":sDate};
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },                              
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events             
                events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                       $.ajax({
                        url: 'service/businessEvents',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: "POST", 
                        data:JSON.stringify(json),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        mimeType: 'application/json',
                        success: function(response) {
                            var events = [];
                            $.each(response, function (idx,infraslist) {
                                var Tile=infraslist.title;
                                var star =infraslist.startTime;
                                var end = infraslist.end;
                                var endt = $.fullCalendar.moment(star);
                                endt = endt.add(end,'hours');
                                //Here pushing the content on calendar
                                events.push({
                                        title: Tile,
                                        start: star,
                                        end: endt
                                           });
                            });
                            callback(events);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                              if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                  alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                              } else {
                                  alert('Unexpected error.'+ errorThrown);
                              }
                          }

                    });
                },
                eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                    if (view.name === "month") {
                    view.calendar.zoomTo(calEvent.start, "agendaWeek");
                    };
                    if (view.name === "agendaWeek") {
                    view.calendar.zoomTo(calEvent.start, "agendaDay");  
                    };
                }               
            }); 
            var NewDate = moment(sDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
//Here the date changes after the below line. If i dont mention the below line the request stops here.
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', NewDate);


    //      
        };
```

Comment: It seems to be issue with respective to flusing the event as old event keeps coming. Can some one help on this.

Comment: Please let me know if more details is needed.

Comment: ever figure this one out? I'm running into a similar issue.